# Нет одновременного движения, проблема с потоками?

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Пробую написать игру Аэрохоккей, думаю суть игры понятна. У меня есть три класса, это основное окно, игровое поле и статистическое поле. Движение шайбы начинается после нажатия кнопки из Статистического поля, осуществляется посредством перерисовки в обработчике таймера.

Вопрос первый: До нажатия этой самой кнопки, игроки могут двигаться(в основном классе), но не одновременно. Я так понимаю проблема в потоках(

Вопрос второй: После нажатия кнопки, свое движение начинает шайба и игроки уже не двигаются. Тут, насколько я понимаю, проблема так же в потоках( 
Не могу осознать как сделать правильно. Как и все тут я только учусь, не судите строго код.

Основной класс:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;


public class MainWindow {

public MainWindow() {
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    // Инициализация фрейма
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setLocation(screenSize.width / 2 - (StatisticField.STATISTIC_FIELD_W + GameField.GAME_FIELD_W) / 2,
            screenSize.height / 2 - StatisticField.STATISTIC_FIELD_H / 2);
    jFrame.setTitle("Air Hockey");
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jFrame.setResizable(false);
    jFrame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_UP) {
                GameField.setPlayer2Y(GameField.getPlayer2Y() - 5);
                jFrame.repaint(5);
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_DOWN) {
                GameField.setPlayer2Y(GameField.getPlayer2Y() + 5);
                jFrame.repaint(5);
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_W) {
                GameField.setPlayer1Y(GameField.getPlayer1Y() - 5);
                jFrame.repaint(5);
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == VK_S) {
                GameField.setPlayer1Y(GameField.getPlayer1Y() + 5);
                jFrame.repaint(5);
            }
        }
    });

    // Создание игрового и статистического поля
    StatisticField statisticField = new StatisticField();
    GameField gameField = new GameField();
    statisticField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(StatisticField.STATISTIC_FIELD_W, StatisticField.STATISTIC_FIELD_H));
    gameField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GameField.GAME_FIELD_W, GameField.GAME_FIELD_H));

    jFrame.add(gameField);
    jFrame.add(statisticField);
    jFrame.pack();

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
}
}
```

Класс игрового поля:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class GameField extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static final int WIN_POINTS = 7;                     // Очков для победы
public static int GAME_FIELD_H = 400;                     // Высота игрового поля
public final static int GAME_FIELD_W = 700;            // Ширина игрового поля
private final static int PUCK_SIZE = 20;                     // Размер шайбы
private final static int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 100;           // Высота игроков
private final static int PLAYER_WIDTH = 15;             // Ширина игроков
private int puckX;                                                          // Х-координата шайбы
private int puckY;                                                          // У-координата шайбы
private static int player1X;                                                     // Х-координата 1-го игрока
private static int player1Y;                                                     // У-координата 1-го игрока
private static int player2X;                                                    // Х-координата 2-го игрока
private static int player2Y;                                                    // У-координата 2-го игрока
private static int player1Points;                                     // Очки 1-го игрока
private static int player2Points;                                    // Очки 2-го игрока
private  Timer timerPuck;                                           // Время перерисовки
private boolean puckUp;                                               // Направление движения шайбы
private boolean puckDown;
private boolean puckLeft;
private boolean puckRight;
private static boolean player1Up = false;                              // Направление движения игроков
private static boolean player1Down = false;
private static boolean player2Up = false;
private static boolean player2Down = false;
private static boolean inGame = false;
private int route;                                                        // Начальное направление движения шайбы

public static int getPlayer1Y() {
    return player1Y;
}

public static void setPlayer1Y(int player1Y) {
    GameField.player1Y = player1Y;
}

public static int getPlayer2Y() {
    return player2Y;
}

public static void setPlayer2Y(int player2Y) {
    GameField.player2Y = player2Y;
}

public static boolean isInGame() {
    return inGame;
}

public static void setInGame(boolean inGame) {
    GameField.inGame = inGame;
}

// Отрисовка шайбы и игроков
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D player1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(player1X, player1Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
        Rectangle2D player2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(player2X, player2Y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
        Ellipse2D puck = new Ellipse2D.Double(puckX, puckY, PUCK_SIZE, PUCK_SIZE);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fill(puck);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(player1);
        g2.fill(player2);
}

// Движение шайбы
public void movePuck() {
    if(puckUp)
        puckY -= 1;
    if(puckDown)
        puckY += 1;
    if(puckLeft)
    puckX -= 1;
    if(puckRight)
        puckX += 1;
}

// Выбор начального направления движения шайбы
public void choiceOfDirection(){
    route = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    if (route == 0) {
        puckRight = true;
        puckUp = true;
        puckLeft = false;
        puckDown = false;
    }
    if (route == 1) {
        puckRight = false;
        puckUp = true;
        puckLeft = true;
        puckDown = false;
    }

    if (route == 2) {
        puckRight = false;
        puckUp = false;
        puckLeft = true;
        puckDown = true;
    }

    if (route == 3) {
        puckRight = true;
        puckUp = false;
        puckLeft = false;
        puckDown = true;
    }
}

// Инициализация игры
public void initGame(){
    player1Points = 0;
    player2Points = 0;

    choiceOfDirection();

    // Начальные координаты шайбы и игроков
    puckX = GAME_FIELD_W/2 - PUCK_SIZE/2;
    puckY = GAME_FIELD_H/2 - PUCK_SIZE/2;
    player1X = 0;
    player1Y = GAME_FIELD_H/2 - PLAYER_HEIGHT/2;
    player2X = GAME_FIELD_W - PLAYER_WIDTH;
    player2Y = GAME_FIELD_H/2 - PLAYER_HEIGHT/2;

    timerPuck = new Timer(1, this);
    timerPuck.start();
}

public GameField() {
    // Установка рамки
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder()));
    // Инициализация игры в конструкторе
    initGame();
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void playerWin(Label player){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            this,
            player.getText() + " WIN!!!",
            "Congratulations",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    StatisticField.getStart().setLabel("Start Game");
    initGame();
    StatisticField.getPoint1().setText("0");
    StatisticField.getPoint2().setText("0");
}

// Проверка на столкновение шайбы с бортами и на гол
public void checkBorder(){
    if(puckY == 0){
        puckDown = true;
        puckUp = false;
    }

    if(puckY == GAME_FIELD_H - PUCK_SIZE){
        puckDown = false;
        puckUp = true;
    }


    if(puckX == PLAYER_WIDTH &&
            puckY + PUCK_SIZE/2 >= player1Y &&
            puckY + PUCK_SIZE/2 <= player1Y + PLAYER_HEIGHT){
        puckRight = true;
        puckLeft = false;
    }

    if(puckX == -PUCK_SIZE){
        player2Points++;
        inGame = false;
        choiceOfDirection();
        puckX = GAME_FIELD_W/2 - PUCK_SIZE/2;
        puckY = GAME_FIELD_H/2 - PUCK_SIZE/2;
        StatisticField.getPoint2().setText("" + player2Points);
        if(player2Points == WIN_POINTS){
            playerWin(StatisticField.getPlayer2Name());
        }
    }

    if(puckX == GAME_FIELD_W - PUCK_SIZE - PLAYER_WIDTH &&
            puckY + PUCK_SIZE/2 >= player2Y &&
            puckY + PUCK_SIZE/2 <= player2Y + PLAYER_HEIGHT){
        puckLeft = true;
        puckRight = false;
    }

    if(puckX == GAME_FIELD_W + PUCK_SIZE){
        player1Points++;
        inGame = false;
        choiceOfDirection();
        puckX = GAME_FIELD_W/2 - PUCK_SIZE/2;
        puckY = GAME_FIELD_H/2 - PUCK_SIZE/2;
        StatisticField.getPoint1().setText("" + player1Points);
        if(player1Points == WIN_POINTS){
            playerWin(StatisticField.getPlayer1Name());
        }
    }
}

// Событие таймера
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(inGame) {
        movePuck();
        checkBorder();
        repaint();
    }
}

}
```

Класс статистического поля:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class StatisticField extends JPanel {

public final  static int STATISTIC_FIELD_H = 400;                                        // Высота статистического поля
public final static int STATISTIC_FIELD_W = 200;                                        // Ширина статистического поля

// Компоненты
private static Label player1Name = new Label("Player 1", Label.CENTER);

private static Label player2Name = new Label("Player 2", Label.CENTER);

private TextField player1NameTextField = new TextField();
private TextField player2NameTextField = new TextField();

private static Label point1 = new Label("0", Label.CENTER);
private static Label point2 = new Label("0", Label.CENTER);

private static Button start = new Button("Start Game");

public static Label getPoint1() {
    return point1;
}

public static Label getPoint2() {
    return point2;
}

public static Label getPlayer1Name() {
    return player1Name;
}

public static Label getPlayer2Name() {
    return player2Name;
}

public static Button getStart() {
    return start;
}

public StatisticField(){

    // Шрифт счета
    Font font = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 100);

    // Компоненты
    JPanel settingPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel setting1player = new JPanel();
    JPanel setting2player = new JPanel();
    JPanel points = new JPanel();
    Label colon = new Label(":", Label.CENTER);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(), BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    Label setting1Up = new Label("\"W\" - UP", Label.CENTER);
    Label setting2Up = new Label("\"UP\" - UP", Label.CENTER);
    Label setting1Down = new Label("\"S\" - DOWN", Label.CENTER);
    Label setting2Down = new Label("\"DOWN\" - DOWN", Label.CENTER);
    Button renamePlayer1 = new Button("Rename");
    Button renamePlayer2 = new Button("Rename");

    // Установка менеджеров компановки
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    setting1player.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    setting2player.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    settingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    points.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

    // Установка рамок
    settingPanel.setBorder(border);
    points.setBorder(border);

    // Установка шрифта
    point1.setFont(font);
    point2.setFont(font);
    colon.setFont(font);

    // Добавление на панель points
    points.add(point1);
    points.add(colon);
    points.add(point2);

    // Добавление на панель setting1player
    setting1player.add(player1Name);
    setting1player.add(setting1Up);
    setting1player.add(setting1Down);
    setting1player.add(player1NameTextField);
    setting1player.add(renamePlayer1);

    // Добавление на панель setting2player
    setting2player.add(player2Name);
    setting2player.add(setting2Up);
    setting2player.add(setting2Down);
    setting2player.add(player2NameTextField);
    setting2player.add(renamePlayer2);

    // Добавление на панель settingPanel
    settingPanel.add(setting1player);
    settingPanel.add(setting2player);

    // Добавление на статистическое поле
    add(points);
    add(settingPanel);
    add(start);

    // Обработчик кнопки start
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            start.setLabel("Continue Game");
            GameField.setInGame(true);
        }
    });

    // Обработчик кнопки renamePlayer1
    renamePlayer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!player1NameTextField.getText().equals("")) {
                player1Name.setText(player1NameTextField.getText());
                player1NameTextField.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    // Обработчик кнопки renamePlayer2
    renamePlayer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!player2NameTextField.getText().equals("")) {
                player2Name.setText(player2NameTextField.getText());
                player2NameTextField.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Показывайте уже все! класс статистического поля - в студию

Comment: Тут нет необходимости создавать потоки для игроков. Вся работа ваших потоков заключается в СОЗДАНИИ И ДОБАВЛЕНИИ листенеров. Всё. Поток прекратил свою работу. А неодновременность управления, думаю, связана с тем как обрабатываются клавиши. Очевидно, таким способом невозможно отследить одновременное нажатие клавиш.

Comment: Да, то что потоки работают не так, как я планировал я понял, поправлю. Дайте наводку как обеспечить одновременность движений и игроков и шайбы

Comment: Спасибо за замечания и советы, буду пробовать)

Comment: Тут проблема в фокусе (focus). Когда нажимается что-нибудь на стат. панели, ваша форма теряет фокус, а `keyListener` не работает без фокуса.

Comment: В классе `MainWindow` я сделал `jFrame` не локальной, а `static JFrame jFrame;` и в обработчике кнопки `start` добавил в конце `MainWindow.jFrame.requestFocus();`

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно одна проблема решилась! Осталось добиться одновременности движения игроков)